How do you compute the Fresnel coefficients for total reflection between two lossy materials?
I've implemented the transfer-matrix method to compute the reflectance/transmittance of a multilayer stack of thin films, and I'm wondering if the technique can be extended to deal with cases of total reflection, where the refracted angle is imaginary.
In the typical situation, where the refracted angle is real, the Fresnel coefficients are
$$
r_{ij} = \frac{q_i - q_j}{q_i + q_j}
$$
and
$$
t_{ij} = \frac{2 q_i}{q_i + q_j}
$$
where
$$
q_k = \begin{cases}
n_k \cos \theta_k & s\text{-polarized} \\
\frac{1}{n_k} \cos \theta_k & p\text{-polarized},
\end{cases}
$$
$n_k$ is the complex index of refraction inside material $k$, and $\theta_k$ is the angle between the propagation direction and the interface normal inside material $k$.
To determine $\cos \theta_j$, we use Snell's law and the Pythagorean theorem to convert sines to cosines
$$
\begin{align}
\cos \theta_j &= \pm \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \theta _j} \\
              &= \pm \sqrt{1 - \left[ \text{Re} \left( \frac{n_i}{n_j} \right) \sin \theta_i \right]^2},
\end{align}
$$
but if $\text{Re}(n_j / n_i) = \sin \theta_i$, $\cos \theta_j$ is imaginary, and we get a case similar to total reflection (except not all the energy is reflected due to the lossy nature of the interface).
According to Born and Wolf 7th edition, page 50, we need to take the negative sign in front of the square root so that the field tends to zero at $+\infty$, but in my code I find that I only need to use the negative sign for the $s$-polarized case (otherwise the coefficients become nonphysical), and $q_k$ becomes
$$
q_k = \begin{cases}
n_k (\cos \theta_k)^* & s\text{-polarized} \\
\frac{1}{n_k} \cos \theta_k & p\text{-polarized}.
\end{cases}
$$
Does anyone know if what I've done here has any validity at all? I'm pretty worried about only taking the complex conjugate of $\cos \theta_k$ for the $s$-polarization for symmetry reasons. If someone could tell me for certain that both polarization states should be treated the same I would know there's a bug elsewhere in my code.
Also Sigel 2022 seems to indicate that this attempt is misinformed from the start, and there's hidden singularities which need to be treated using a totally different technique.
